# Why I cant modify the original array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to change the comments in each post by the number of comments, but The arrays keep the original data when I put in the answer of express.

I tried use another Object and map instead foreach but nothing works.

```
router.get('/',  function(req, res, next) { 

    postModel.find({}, function(err, posts){
      if(err){
        next(err)
      }else{
        posts.forEach((post,i) => {
          posts[i].comments= post.comments.length;
        });
        res.json({ status: 'success' ,message: "Posts Encontrados!!" , data : {posts: posts}});
      }
    });

  });
```

New code:

```
router.get('/',  async function(req, res, next) { //get all posts
```

var p;

```
await postModel.find({}, function(err, posts){

  if(err){
    next(err)
  }else{
    p= posts;
    //res.json({ status: 'success' ,message: "Posts Encontrados!!" , data : {posts: posts}});
  }
});
p.forEach((post,i) => {
  p[i].comments= post.comments.length;
});

res.json({ status: 'success' ,message: "Posts Encontrados!!" , data : {posts: p}});
```

});

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn He wants to replace each comment with its length, there's nothing about a total here.

Comment: I can't see any reason why the code wouldn't work. You can also write `post.comments = post.comments.length;`

Comment: thanks, but is still not working...

Comment: Your code works here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/0871amLd/3/

Comment: yes, but in my code is not working, I tried using the foreach out of the find function but i'm still the same result.

Comment: There must be something more to the problem that you're not showing. Don't forget that `.find()` is asynchronous, you can't access the result outside of the callback function.

Comment: But `res.json()` is in the proper place, the data being sent to the client should be correct.

Comment: this is the new code:
`router.get('/',  async function(req, res, next) { //get all posts
  var p;
    await postModel.find({}, function(err, posts){
   
      if(err){
        next(err)
      }else{
        p= posts;
        //res.json({ status: 'success' ,message: "Posts Encontrados!!" , data : {posts: posts}});
      }
    });
    p.forEach((post,i) => {
      p[i].comments= post.comments.length;
    });
    
    res.json({ status: 'success' ,message: "Posts Encontrados!!" , data : {posts: p}});
  
  });`

Comment: Don't put code in comments, add an update to the question.

Comment: What's the difference other than the variable `p`?

Comment: could be a context problem but not is the same result. the P variable contents the posts.
here the result https://gyazo.com/4183cd73dbb35819a8eaa222f52372f0

Comment: The problem isn't variable scope. The problem is that `find()` is asynchronous. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

`forEach()` does not mutate the array on which it is called (although callback, if invoked, may do so).

If you do need to change the original array, use either`.map()`.

For example:

```
posts = posts.map(post => {
post.comments = post.comments.length;
return post
});
```

This will transform the original array and return your desired values.